# Can Apache Spark speed up the process of reading millions of records from Oracle DB and then writing these to a file?

Tags: java, oracle, apache-spark, mapreduce, spark-streaming

I am new to Apache-Spark,

I have a requirement to read millions(~5 million) of records from Oracle database, then do some processing on these records , and write the processed records to a file.

At present ,this is done in Java , and in this process
 - the records in DB are categorized into different sub sets, based on some data criteria 
 - In the Java process, 4 threads are running in parallel 
 - Each thread reads a sub set of records , processes and writes processed records to a new file
 - finally it  merges all these files into single file.

Still It takes around half an hour to complete the  whole process .

So I  would like to know , if Apache Spark could make this process fast- read millions of records from Oracle DB, process these,  and write to a file ?

If Spark can make this process faster, what is the best approach to be used to implement this in my process? Also wWill it be effective in a non-clustered environment too?

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Why not do the processing in PL/SQL? Eliminate at least one chunk of unnecessary I/O

Comment: Have you measured where is the limit in the current setup? Is it the processing speed of your java app or rather the seek/transfer speed from the DB?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can do that using Spark, it's built for distributed processing ! http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases

You should be using a well configured spark cluster to achieve the same. Performance is something you need to fine tune by adding more worker nodes as required.